# What is a SharePoint Server Side File Hander?

Tags: security

The definition of the 'View Only' permissions level is as follows:

> Members of this group can view pages,
>   list items, and documents. If the
>   document has a server-side file
>   handler available, they can only view
>   the document using the *server-side
>   file handler*.

What is considered to be a server-side file handler in the context of SharePoint? Is this an [HTTPHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)? What technology is it based on, how do I write one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been answered (more or less) on the [StackOverflow version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336599/what-is-a-sharepoint-server-side-file-hander).

Answer (score 1):

Server-side file handler is something like Excel Web Services, or HTML Viewer, I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an explanation [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/e0edb245-41fc-4a29-89a6-4fdc1348ca5a)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain it at all (I came across that post as well during my initial investigation).

Answer (score 0):

I think it mainly refers to ASPX files being executed on the server before returning data rather than downloading the actual ASPX file.